# How to efficiently use 2D pointers instead of 2D arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, 2d

I need use pointers for this code. No arrays, no structures. For example, if I need an array of floats to hold the scores, do not use float score[15]. Rather use float *score, then use dynamic memory allocation to hold required memory. I must use memory optimally, that is if you have only 6 scores, I need to use to point to a memory chunk of sizeof(float)*6 bytes. Similarly, to hold a name, instead of doing it with 2D char arrays, use 2D pointers (char firstName[15][20] → char **firstName).

I have the code in C below, I need help using 2d pointers. The Code compiles and runs, But after I enter the names if crashes and after working on it so long I'm stuck.

Thank you in advance

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void Option_Scren();

void print_records(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score);
void search_by_firstname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score);
void search_by_lastname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score);
void sort_by_score(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score);
void sort_by_lastname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score);


int main(void)
{
    char **First_Name;
    char **Last_Name;
    float *Score_;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = -1;

    First_Name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    Last_Name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    Score_ = (float *)malloc(sizeof(int)*15);
    for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        First_Name[i] = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        Last_Name[i] = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    }

    //char *nametofind = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));

    printf("Please indicate the number of records you want to enter (min 5, max 15):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with the following format \nFirstname Lastname Score\n");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %s %f", &First_Name[i][0], &Last_Name[i][0], &Score_[i]);
    }
    do
    {
        printf("\n---you may access the records by---\n");
        printf("Print records (press 1)\n");
        printf("Search by first name (press 2)\n");
        printf("Search by last name (press 3)\n");
        printf("Sort by score (press 4)\n");
        printf("Sort by last name (press 5)\n");
        printf("Exit program (press 0)\n");
        printf("--------------------------\n\n");
        printf("Please a function by entering a value from 0 to 5.\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("You have selected option: %d\n", x);
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            print_records(n, First_Name, Last_Name, Score_);
            break;
        case 2:
            search_by_firstname(n, First_Name, Last_Name, Score_);
            break;
        case 3:
            search_by_lastname(n, First_Name, Last_Name, Score_);
            break;
        case 4:
            sort_by_score(n, First_Name, Last_Name, Score_);
            break;
        case 5:
            sort_by_lastname(n, First_Name, Last_Name, Score_);
            break;
        default: printf("Please only enter a number from 0 to 5\n");
        }
    }
    while (x != 0);
    printf("Thank You \nGood Bye\n");
    return 0;
}

void print_records(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("First Name: %s, Last Name: %s, Score: %.2f\n", firstname[i], lastname[i], score[i]);
    }
}

void search_by_firstname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *Name_Search = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    printf("Please enter the first name of student record you wish to print: ");

    fgets(Name_Search, 20, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(Name_Search, firstname[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("First Name: %s, Last Name: %s, Score: %.2f\n", firstname[i], lastname[i], score[i]);
        }
    }
}

void search_by_lastname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *Name_Search = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    printf("Please enter last name of student record you wish to print: ");

    fgets(Name_Search, 20, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(Name_Search, lastname[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("First Name: %s, Last Name: %s, Score: %.2f\n", firstname[i], lastname[i], score[i]);
        }
    }
}

void sort_by_score(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float tempscore;
    char tempfirstname[20];
    char templastname[20];
    // bubble sort
    for (i = 0; i<size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (score[j]>score[j + 1])
            {
                tempscore = score[j];
                score[j] = score[j + 1];
                score[j + 1] = tempscore;
                strcpy(tempfirstname, firstname[j]);
                strcpy(firstname[j], firstname[j + 1]);
                strcpy(firstname[j + 1], tempfirstname);
                strcpy(templastname, lastname[j]);
                strcpy(lastname[j], lastname[j + 1]);
                strcpy(lastname[j + 1], templastname);
            }
        }
    }
    print_records(size, firstname, lastname, score);
}

void sort_by_lastname(int size, char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float tempscore;
    char tempfirstname[20];
    char templastname[20];
    // bubble sort
    for (i = 0; i<size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(lastname[j], lastname[j + 1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(tempfirstname, firstname[j]);
                strcpy(firstname[j], firstname[j + 1]);
                strcpy(firstname[j + 1], tempfirstname);
                strcpy(templastname, lastname[j]);
                strcpy(lastname[j], lastname[j + 1]);
                strcpy(lastname[j + 1], templastname);
                tempscore = score[j];
                score[j] = score[j + 1];
                score[j + 1] = tempscore;
            }
        }
    }
    print_records(size, firstname, lastname, score);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to debug on yourself? Could you give as an output of an error?

Comment: You need to ask the user how many records they want *before* allocating memory.

Comment: I tried moving it before the records are being called and it still crashes.

Comment: something minor - you should add a `case 0: break;`. Otherwise you'll drop down to `default:` and print the error message erroneously

Comment: Are these constraints for real code or is this just an assignment? If it is the later, your instructor is really bad. I don't understand why pseudo arrays are still taught in classes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are doing is to use dynamic allocated storage for some data, the way you did allocation has some problem, see below. Also, don't cast return value of `malloc`, `void*` is compatible to other pointers in standard C. Second, you don't need do `sizeof(char)`, it's defined to be `1` in the standard.

```
// suppose the number of elements you want to store if 15
#define N 15
char **First_Name;
char **Last_Name;
float *Score_;

// First_Name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
// you are allocating an buffer to hold ONE char* here, use following instead
First_Name = malloc(N * sizeof(char*));

// Last_Name = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
// same issue here, should be:
Last_Name = malloc(N * sizeof(char*));

// Score_ = (float *)malloc(sizeof(int)*15);
// Score_ is an pointer of floats, so you cannot use sizeof(int) to calculate the size
Score_ = malloc(N * sizeof(float));

for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
     First_Name[i] = malloc(20);
     Last_Name[i] = malloc(20);
}
```

Comment: probably want to comment out or delete the `Score_ = (float *)malloc(sizeof(int)*15);` line

Comment: I think you also want `Last_Name = malloc(N * sizeof(char*));`